# Export Makers, Symbol Visibility, ...?

Tags: c++, c, api, gcc, visual-c++

I am trying to develop a library which has to be platform independent. While writing library API, it is a good practice making some prefixes for the functions with the some preprocessor defines.

For example, Windows API has WINAPI, OpenMPI has OMPI_DECLSPEC and so on...

OpenMPI:

```
OMPI_DECLSPEC  int MPI_Init(int *argc, char ***argv);
```

OpenGL:

```
GLAPI void GLAPIENTRY glBegin( GLenum mode );
```

With this preprocessor defines, programmers can set export options, visibilities, calling conventions for functions in the library. At OpenGL function declarations, as you can see, there are two different preprocessor defines.

What is the name of this prefix in the literature?

**Edit:** https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility in this page, the topic is discussed. I think, this kind of macros deserves a special name. We could name it as "visibility macro" or something, but this macro can set other kind of things according to compiler, OS, etc...

Comment: You posted that same question some hours ago already! Don't! If the question was closed, edit to comply to site rules and ask to re-open. Also it heavily depends on the language you use. C and C++ are different languages. Do not ask for solutions in both languages, but only the one you intend to use.

Comment: No they cannot. You just can use the pretty small common subset or compile C syntax with a C++ compiler, ignore different semantics and hope for the best. Anyway, you missed the actual point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a specific name for these types of macros, but if I were to have to give these a name, I would have to label them "*context macros*" or (more specific to functions) "*function attribute portability context macros*" since they are typically defined based on the context of the compilation unit.

This could be further split into additional categories:

- *Portability macros* for example:

  - `__attribute__()` vs. `__declspec()`
  - `__attribute__((always_inline))` vs. `__forceinline`
  - or defining unsupported attributes as empty
- *Compilation context* macros

  - `static` vs `extern`
  - visibility context macros (hidden, default, protected, internal/symbolic,...)

Portability context macros are used to overcome the differences between compilers and/or host/target architectures and operating systems.  These cover more than just differences between visibility (including any special function attributes)

Compilation context macros can allow the same source to be used for effeciently compiling for different types of compilation such as a static vs PIC and library vs. binary.  These may include various inline or visibility directives depending on the compilation context.

In the example given

```
GLAPI void GLAPIENTRY glBegin( GLenum mode );
```

The **`GLAPI`** would represent a compilation context (probably also with associated portability macros) and the **`GLAPIENTRY`** is just a portability macro wrapper for a specific set of function attributes (it is a "cross-platform" API).

Answer (score 3):

> What is the name of this prefix in the literature?

They are called [*macros*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html).  They facilitate conditional compilation in the C and C++ languages.  They were also used as substitute for `typedef`s back in the days.  Take `GLAPIENTRY` for instance, it's defined thus:

```
#define GLAPIENTRY __stdcall
```

If the author has to change the calling convention to `__cdecl`, if `__stdcall` was directly put in the function declaration, then for every function this has to be changed.  However, with the macro, just redefining would do:

```
#define GLAPIENTRY __cdecl
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this kind of macros deserve a special name.

Comment: Sure, they may deserve a special name, but I don't think there's one already for them.